# Array - runtime error: index out of bounds for type 'int [*]'

Tags: c++, arrays

The user can enter two integer number n, k: k < n.

Now one must enter n arbitrary integer numbers which i want to store in an array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n, k;
    int scores[n];  
    cin >> n >> k;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        cin >> scores[i];
    }   
}
```

For n = 5 , k = 3 I get the following error message after entering the third random number

```
untitled.cpp:13:18: runtime error: index 3 out of bounds for type 'int [*]'
```

How can scores[3] be out of bounds if the total array "scores" consists of 5 elements?

Comment: If a C++ compiler does not yell compiling the above code, a better C++ compiler should be used. Modern C++ compilers shouldn't have any issues generating a warning message for these kinds of simple mistakes.

Comment: `int scores[n];` in standard `c++`  the variable `n` must be a compile time constant. VLAs are not allowed by the standard. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Answer (score 3):

Before reading data, `n` is not initialized and have indeterminate value.

Usages of `n` must be after reading.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n, k;  
    cin >> n >> k;
    int scores[n]; // move this
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        cin >> scores[i];
    }   
}
```

Also note that variable-length array like this is not in the standard of C++. Consider using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n, k;  
    cin >> n >> k;
    vector<int> scores(n);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        cin >> scores[i];
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thx for the hint! How would i define a 2d array with n rows and k columns int[n][k] with std::vector vector? I tried vector<vector<int> > matrix(rows,columns) but it does not work.

Comment: Using constructor `vector<type>(num, initial_value)`, it can be written as `vector<vector<int> > matrix(rows, vector<int>(columns))`